# C# Xna cut out any form from a Texture2D "intelligent" and automatic

Tags: c#, xna, crop, texture2d

I just started making my own mapgenerator. I finished the perlin noise yesterday. The problem now is that it gives me a texture with more wholes in it than a swiss cheese!... So i planned to make some code to cut out one of the wholes with some kind of automatic algorithm. Later i could blend them together on some background and make many different sized caves and ores and so on. Now i need an algorithm that can cut out one cave and put it on an alpha channel.

The way i would do it now is making my own method wich needs X and Y as parameter. This method would check if the pixel at the Coordinates is black. If it is it puts this pixel down on a 2d-Texture and it would call itself with the Coordinates of the pixels that are located next to the pixel it checked. if the pixel is not black it does nothing. I would also have to make sure the pixels will only get checked once.

Now do you think this is a clever way of generating my terrain, ores, caves, etc?

[image]

Comment: i would make 2 or 3 versions of the perlin texture and then blend them with an adding blend mode. this way you will get less holes with every blend operation

Comment: yeah i tried that. The problem is that i want long/big caves and small caves and not only small caves... Just like in any mining game. There are small caves and sometime there are caves that are very very long.